# Datatable does not update after rows removed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

i have a datatable using the primefaces library, and while i have got all the functions working i have just one small issue, when i press the command link to remove the row, it works and the row gets removed but it does not automatically update the datatable to reflect this, ideally what i want is when the user presses the delete button it automatically updates the datatable to show this, how can i achieve this ?

here is the datatable

```
                        <p:dataTable id="UserTable"
                                     widgetVar="usersTable" 
                                     value="#{userdetailsController.items}"
                                     var="item"
                                     emptyMessage="No details was found with given criteria">
                            <!--filteredValue="{userdetailsController.filteredUsers}" -->

                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <p:outputPanel>  
                                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields: " />  
                                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="usersTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />  
                                </p:outputPanel>  
                            </f:facet>

                            <p:column id="USERID" filterBy="id"   
                                      headerText="i.d."  
                                      filterMatchMode="contains">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsTitle_id}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                            </p:column>

                            <!--There are four different match modes, "startsWith"(default), "endsWith", "contains" and "exact"-->
                            <p:column id="USERNAME" filterBy="username"   
                                      headerText="username."   
                                      filterMatchMode="contains">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsTitle_username}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.username}"/>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <p:commandLink action="#{userdetailsController.prepareView}" value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsViewLink}"/>
                                <h:outputText value=" "/>
                                <div class="divider"/>
                                <p:commandLink action="#{userdetailsController.prepareEdit}" value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsEditLink}"/>
                                <h:outputText value=" "/>
                                <div class="divider"/>
                                <p:commandLink action="#{userdetailsController.destroy}" value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsDestroyLink}"/>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the update attribute of the p:commandLink to tell PF you want to do the ajax request to obtain all data related to table UserTable like this:

```
            <p:commandLink actionListener="#{userdetailsController.destroy}" value="#{bundle.ListUserdetailsDestroyLink}" ajax="true" update="UserTable"/>
```

Make sure to use actionListener as it is called before action atrib. A more detailed example is here 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandLink.jsf

Answer (score -1):

Per the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()), you need to make a call to Draw() after you remove a row.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'img.icon-delete', function () {
    table
        .row( $(this).parents('tr') )
        .remove()
        .draw();
} );
```